Headers are read-only, response has already started on Blazor Server SignInManager PasswordSignInAsync
This is my login page:

    @page "/Login"
    
    @inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
    @inject ILogger<Login> Logger
    @inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
    
    <PageTitle>Se connecter</PageTitle>
    
    <h1>Se connecter</h1>
    
    @if (errorMessage != null)
    {
        <MudAlert Severity="Severity.Error">@errorMessage</MudAlert>
    }
    <MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.Small">
    <MudCard>
        <EditForm Model="@Input" OnValidSubmit="Submit">
            <MudCardContent>
                <MudTextField @bind-Value="Input.Email"
                              For="@(() => Input.Email)"
                              Immediate="true"
                              Label="Courriel" />

                <MudTextField @bind-Value="Input.Password"
                              For="@(() => Input.Password)"
                              Immediate="true"
                              Label="Mot de passe"
                              InputType="InputType.Password" />
            </MudCardContent>
            <MudCardActions>
                @if (InProgress)
                {
                    <MudProgressCircular Color="Color.Primary" Indeterminate="true" Class="ml-auto" />
                }
                else
                {
                    <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" Class="ml-auto" ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit">Se connecter</MudButton>
                }
            </MudCardActions>
        </EditForm>
    </MudCard>
</MudContainer>
    
    @code {
        private string? errorMessage = null;
        private bool InProgress = false;
    
        [SupplyParameterFromForm]
        private InputModel Input { get; set; } = new();
    
        private async Task Submit()
        {
            InProgress = true;
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, false, lockoutOnFailure: true);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                Logger.LogInformation("L'utilisateur est connecté.");
                NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Home");
            }
            else if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                Logger.LogWarning("Le compte a été bloqué.");
                errorMessage = "Le compte a été bloqué.";
            }
            else
            {
                errorMessage = "Erreur: tentative de connexion invalide.";
            }
            InProgress = false;
        }
    
        private sealed class InputModel
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Le courriel ne doit pas être vide.")]
            [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Ceci n'est pas une adresse courriel valide.")]
            public string Email { get; set; } = "";
    
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Le mot de passe ne doit pas être vide.")]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; } = "";
        }
    }

When I log in with a user, it is loading and it never ends loading. So I put a breakpoint and I notice that the call stop at this line:

var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email,
Input.Password, false, lockoutOnFailure: true);

with infinite loop. I get no error message at all. It is just that it never ends loading. I do not know what can I do to get it working...
This is my Routes tag in App.razor:

<Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />

I discovered that I got this error in console:
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost[111]
      Unhandled exception in circuit 'p1W8tSWhUaRGiR9ur-mhK8l0QIyLyyDYpUF8eGrBwRY'.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Headers are read-only, response has already started.


SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync actually needs to access
"httpcontext" to work.  But "httpcontext" is only available in SSR rendermode.
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-8.0#ihttpcontextaccessorhttpcontext-in-razor-components-blazor)
So you have to use SSR for this page. Editform also works in SSR without "interactive". ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#static-server-side-rendering-static-ssr )
Since you are using global rendermode, you could modify App.razor like following:
...
    <Routes @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />
...
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;
//null rendermode represents SSR.
    private IComponentRenderMode? RenderModeForPage => HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Login") ? null : InteractiveServer;
}

